# How to fetch data of specific user

Tags: mysql

I am developing cargo booking site for private cargo company. I have given facility to user that they can book the flight after registration. and admin will generate quotation according to user's input. I have created quotation form but I want to fetch specific user data in that form. can anybody guide how to do?

Comment: Ok.. Like new user will register and book the cargo in the following table

Fight | Route | Currency | Date | Time | Departure | Arrival | No of Passengers |Lugguage Weight in KG

G5550 | Oneway | USD | 05/05/2016| 02:00 | Mumbai | Dubai | 15 | 450

Comment: @pravinkumarkhairnar Here [SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: Following is list of booking
User | Fight | Route | Currency | Date | Time | Departure | Qtn | Inv
Regd USR | G5550 | Oneway | USD | 05/05/2016| 02:00 | Mum | Du | 15 | 450 | Qtn btn | INV btn 
Now Quotation page, where I want to fetch record which were entered in above tables but that should be user specific..Please help

Answer (score 0):

> Following is list of booking User | Fight | Route | Currency | Date |
>   Time | Departure | Qtn | Inv Regd USR | G5550 | Oneway | USD |
>   05/05/2016| 02:00 | Mum | Du | 15 | 450 | Qtn btn | INV btn Now
>   Quotation page, where I want to fetch record which were entered in
>   above tables but that should be user specific..Please help –

So now you have a Table called "booking" in your MySQL Database. You can write a Native SQL to retrieve the record of a "User" with a specific "user_id". Here we also assume that we have a way of dynamically knowing & retrieving the "user_id" (perhaps from a session or via any API or so). Assuming you are using PHP; your SQL Query could read something like this:

```
<?php
    //YOU MUST HAVE A WAY OF ACCESSING THE USER-TOKEN: PERHAPS YOU ALREADY HAVE A USER OBJECT IN THE SESSION... IF SO, YOU COULD JUST ACCESS ALL USER DATA DIRECTLY USING THIS OBJECT...
    $user_token = "figure a way to get the user_id or token"; //\User::getLoggedInUserObject(); //ID COMING FROM A DYNAMIC SOURCE, $_SESSION, ETC...
    // IF YOU DON'T HAVE SOMETHING LIKE A GENERIC USER OBJECT BUT JUST USER TOKEN OR ID AND YOU MUST RUN SQL QUERIES; THEN HERE IS THE QUERY...
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE User='" . $user_token  . "' LIMIT 1";
    // WITH A USER: "G5550" YOUR SQL COULD LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS:
    // $sql = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE User='G5550' LIMIT 1";
    //PERFORM THE DATABASE QUERY AND RETRIEVE THE USER OBJECT - USE IT IN YOUR FORM
```

Once you have the Result of the Query, you can then use it to pre-populate the Form...

**If you are using PDO, here is what I'd suggest you do on the quotation page:**

```
<?php
    defined("HOST") or define("HOST", "localhost");
    defined("DBASE") or define("DBASE", "your-database-name");
    defined("USER") or define("USER", "root"); //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-USER
    defined("PASS") or define("PASS", "root"); //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-PASS
    $user_id = "G5550"; // HERE YOU HAVE TO HAVE A WAY OF GETTING THE USER ID OR SO...

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS); 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM booking WHERE User = :user_id');
        $stmt->execute(['user_id' => $user_id]);
        $user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);    //AS OPPOSED TO USING PDO::FETCH_ASSOC SINCE WE ARE INTERESTED IN ONLY ONE USER OBJECT);
        //Now $user is an Object containing all the information you need... Flight, Rout, Date, Time, etc.
        //And you can access each data using its Name: for example - 
        //$user->Route; $user->Departure; $user->Flight;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Now, here is the Fun Part: In your Form, you have to populate the Fields using these Values so that the User doesn't have to re-type the Information again. So, you do this on the form:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="Flight" class="lbl-quotation">Flight:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" class="input-box Flight" id="Flight" value="<?php echo ( isset($user->Flight)? $user->Flight: ""); ?>" /><br/>
        <label for="Route" class="lbl-quotation">Flight:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" class="input-box Route" id="Route" value="<?php echo ( isset($user->Route)? $user->Route: ""); ?>" /><br/>
        <label for="Departure" class="lbl-quotation">Departure:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" class="input-box Departure" id="Departure" value="<?php echo ( isset($user->Departure)? $user->Departure: ""); ?>" /><br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps a bit...